# Reduce raster size in R

Tags: r, size, raster

I need to perform a kmeans analysis on a raster stack, but it's a very large file - more than 100 GB at the moment, so the programm will return a "cannot allocate" error.

What's the best way to reduce the size of the stack below a certain point without altering the data too much? I could try with "resample" but I'm afraid I will lose too much info going from 100GB if I want to keep it below say 1GB, and also I wouldn't know "how much" to resample it.

Edit: also tried the "memory.limit(size)" trick but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to divide the raster into tiles? You could do that, then run a cycle in which you analyse each tile separately and save each of them in a list. I did something similar, for instance:

```
    library("sf")
    r = stack(file.path(wdir,"your_raster"))
    crs(r) <- CRS(paste0("+init=epsg:",projectCRS))
    tilegrid = st_as_sf(as(raster::extent(r), "SpatialPolygons"))
    tilegrid = st_as_sf(st_make_grid(tilegrid, cellsize = 5000))
```

the cell size is up to you, then create the list and start the cycle

```
    raster.list = list()

    for(i in 1:nrow(tilegrid) ){
     ss = tilegrid[i,]
     ss = st_buffer(ss, 25, joinStyle="MITRE", endCapStyle = "FLAT") # da 
     r.crop = crop(r, ss)[[1]]
```

Here you run your analysis on r.crop and at the end of the cycle add
the final raster (r.final) to the list and close the cycle

```
    raster.list[[i]] = r.final
    }
```

Doing so you should work with a lower load of data, if you need a unique raster as the final result it's enough to use the mosaic function, I did this:

```
    raster.list$fun = mean
    raster.list$na.rm = TRUE
    final.raster = do.call(raster::mosaic, raster.list)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I couldn't manage to make it work...where do I create the r.final file?

Comment: In the cycle when you apply for analysis.
For me it was something like this:
          r.final = function(r.crop)
  Where function is a function that is build according to your analysis